# how can i fix the following bug in my qpdf reader application development

Tags: android

I am trying to develop one android pdf reader application by using Qpdf JAR files, they have given one sample code for pdf viewing and editing ,i followed the procedure given by the qpdf reference, and made the changes to my app accordingly, but when i am running this app on the emulator it is stopped. The following is the logcat messages, can any one help me out?

```
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pdfreader/com.pdfreader.SamplePDFViewer}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.qoppa.samples.viewer.QScrollView
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.qoppa.samples.viewer.QScrollView
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.pdfreader.SamplePDFViewer.onCreate(SamplePDFViewer.java:30)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  ... 11 more
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.qoppa.samples.viewer.QScrollView
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
08-20 00:26:26.787: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: contact qoppa support, that would be glad to happen

Answer (score 1):

Encountered and fixed this problem.
This is probably caused by "main.xml" which contains "com.qoppa.samples.viewer.QScrollView".

```
    <com.qoppa.samples.viewer.QScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagepane"
            android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.qoppa.samples.viewer.QScrollView>
```

You need to replace it with your own class to fix it.
For me:

```
    <com.example.qiaoruntao.trypdf08.QScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pagepane"
            android:background="#FFEEEEEE"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.qiaoruntao.trypdf08.QScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.qoppa.samples.viewer.QScrollView
```

You probably haven't declared QScrollView in your manifest?

```
<activity android:name=".QScrollView"
          android:label="QScrollViewActivity"/>
```

Comment: QScrollView is not an activity it is just a view which extends from FrameLayout